# How to change session with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, session

After I check a checkbox the session is filled with `id` but if I check another checkbox the session won't change. I have a code like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='imei' id='a'>
<input type='checkbox' class='imei' id='b'>
<input type='checkbox' class='imei' id='c'>
```

```js
$('.imei').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.imei').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': this.id });
  } else {  
    $.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': '' });
  }
});
```

```php
<?
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['imei'])) 
  {
    $_SESSION['imei'] = $_POST['imei'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes are `.imei`, yet your event handler is on `.asd` ...

Comment: edited... wrong type... haha

Comment: In which case what you have should work fine (although using radios would make more sense than checkboxes). How are you determining that the session is not being updated.

Comment: @Wahyu what is the value that you are receiving on the back end. Can you please log that result over here. Thanks

Comment: i'm using alert when clicking on button... i already try it... just make the class and id name different from my work

Comment: @Gardezi... there no result just want to make a session and edited when i checked a checkbox

Comment: @Wahyu I just tested it on my side and everything is working correctly I'm getting the id that you are sending back

Comment: I still got the wrong result... i get the last id when i refresh my webpage

Comment: @gardezi is there maybe a problem with my apache version or something? im using v5.3.22

Comment: @Wahyu I don't know about that but it is working on my side. If you want to test it your self. Move all of the html js that you have pasted here(assuming that you html js rather then the one posted above ) in a new file and  create a new php file and write the php code in it and test it

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `else` statement with its code in your js script, i mean

```
else {  
$.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': '' });
}
```

remove this, you only need to check `this.id`, try this

```
$('.imei').change(function() {

   if ($( 'input.imei:checked').length < 1){
     $.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': '' } );
   }else {
     $('.imei').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     $.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': this.id });
  }

});
```

Comment: that else is just to make sure user checked a checkbox before do more option so i want to make the session is blank if all the checkbox are unchecked

Comment: then add this `if ( $( 'input.imei:checked' ).length < 1){ $.post('session_write.php', { 'imei': '' } ); }` inside your `onchange`event

Comment: i tested and it works correctly. upload you full code at some fiddle please